# RegEx to include all JavaScript files except foo.js and bar.js

Tags: javascript, regex

Could someone please help me with RegEx?

1. It should include all JavaScript files, except `foo.[contenthash].js` and `bar.[contenthash].js`.
2. It should only skip files where the `foo` or `bar` appears at the beginning of the file name.
3. It should **not** skip partial file name i.e. `fo.[contenthash].js` (please see missing `o` in `foo`) should not be skipped.

Could someone please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead with anchors right at the start:

```
^(?!foo|bar).*\.js$
```

---

In `JavaScript` this could be:

```js
let files = ['test.12345.js', 'foo.12345.js', 'bar.12345.js'];

let regex = /^(?!foo|bar).*\.js$/

files.forEach(function(file) {
    console.log(regex.test(file));
});
```

---

See an additional [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/NzQfoy/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @undefined999: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

files = ["index.js", "index.html", "main.js", "foo.js", "bar.js", "foo.something.js", "foo.something1.js", "bar.something.js", "bar.something1.js", "fo.something.js"]

patternjs = r"^.+\.js$"
patternfoo = r"^fo.+\.js$"
patternbar = r"^ba.+\.js$"
patternexcludefoo = r"^foo\.\w+\.js$"
patternexcludebar = r"^bar\.\w+\.js$"

for file in files:
    resultfoo = re.match(patternfoo, file)
    resultbar = re.match(patternbar, file)
    resultjs = re.match(patternjs, file)
    resultexcludefoo = re.match(patternexcludefoo, file)
    resultexcludebar = re.match(patternexcludebar, file)

    if resultfoo or resultbar:
        print(file + " is js file either of foo type or bar type")

    if resultjs:
        print(file + " is js file")

    if resultexcludefoo or resultexcludebar:
        print(file + " is to be excluded")
```

As you got the strings, you can manipulate the files accordingly

PS: The code maybe somewhat not upto the mark as I had learned RegEx only 2 days ago. This was the code that I came upto. Didn't checked for JavaScript but these patterns may work as well in JavaScript ( It doesn't support lookbehind and I haven't used it in this code)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm hoping to find a new line RegEx solution like the following:

/^(?![^client$|^vendor$]\/.*\.js)/.test('client.7eb29947b4b76c5ae5589a297482c574.js');

Of course, it's working right now, but that's why I am seeking help.

Comment: Didn't get you. Can you please explain further

Comment: The solution should be in `JavaScript`, not in `Python`, I suppose.

Comment: @Mann, thanks for your help. Jan's solution is more suitable for my requirement. Thanks and good luck.